# Writing a MySQL Plugin

Tags: mysql, c, plugins

I am currently looking into writing a plugin for mysql in C. I have been reading and studying MySQL 5.1 Plugin Development ([http://www.amazon.com/MySQL-Plugin-Development-Sergei-Golubchik/dp/1849510601](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849510601)) which has been helping me out a lot. However I can't seem to find any examples that execute queries. I tried Googling for one but couldn't find any relevant examples. My goal for the time being is to write just a simple plugin that after some data is entered into a table will just perform some basic select queries. If anyone would be willing to share a link to such an example or provide one, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't a trigger suffice for this, or is that just an training example?

Comment: Just a training example for me to learn how to write plugins.

Comment: i am too waiting for this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Mysql with C before, however you might want to take a look at these links:

1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-function-overview.html
2. http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

If you know MySql I think those links would be a good starting point at least.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who's written a storage engine plugin, I've found that executing a query from within a MySQL plugin is incredibly difficult. MySQL isn't re-entrant, due to locking within the MySQL process. You could use the MySQL client api (as suggested by chris) to connect to the same server. But it is 99% likely you will simply deadlock the whole server.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this might help, but I have created a small mysql plugin written in C. The plugin basically sets up a function which when triggered from mysql will send information about a remove, insert or update query to a running node socket server.

You can find the repository here:

https://github.com/Cyclonecode/mysql-notification

Answer (score -2):

It sounds to me like it's not a good idea to try to execute queries within a storange engine, because this introduces re-entrancy that the server doesn't handle.

However, it is possible that you could do it from a daemon thread, as the event scheduler already does. Likewise, Handlersocket does something similar (but uses the handler API rather than executing queries).

In any case, it all sounds a bit fishy. If you are just learning, try writing a few UDFs (they're easy).

Comment: Don't know what you mean by sounds a bit fishy as I am just trying to learn how to write a plugin but ok. I will read up on UDF's if you think that would be more applicable for performing queries based off of triggers.